# Mean event rate in negative binomial regression in R - using glmmTMB and emmeans?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, glmm, negative-binomial-distribution, lsmeans

this is my first question here and am not a native speaker, so I'm quite nervous :)

I'm analysing count data, where subjects are observed over a long period of time (ca 3 years) and can have multiple events in that time period.

Some do have multiple, some don't have any. The total observed time is cut up into 9 timeslots and I'm interested in the marginal mean event rate in each timeslot.

I run a negative binomial GLMM using the following command:

```r
library(glmmTMB)
library(emmeans)

model  <- glmmTMB(event ~  group*timeslot  
                  + (1|ID) #ID is the subject identifier
                  + offset(log(days_in_timeslot )) #time in each timeslot can vary for IDs
                  , data = df #my dataframe
                  , family=binomial)

modelmeans <- emmeans(model
                    , c("group", "timeslot")
                    , adjust = "Tukey"
                    , options = list(tran = "logit")
                    , type = "response"
                    )
```

`emmeans` marks the outcome of this as "prob" or probability. However, the negative binomial regression's coefficients are log(event rate ratio). Is there a way to get the estimated marginal mean event rate from this or would I have to use Poisson regression? Poisson is not fitting my data and zero inflated Poisson is unwanted.

Comment: I do not use emmeans but perhaps the help for the type or options parameters may be a fruitful place to look.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. It's my first time really using emmeans as well. I re-read the options and type topics - and I'm still not sure if what I'm using is right. Maybe someone who knows the function better will elaborate on that.

Comment: Please don't be nervous; the people here are generally friendly. I know a lot about emmeans (I'm its developer) but am not a wizard at all with glmmTMB. It seems to me that you somehow want to fit a NEGATIVE binomial model, not binomial. I hope somebody else can help with the modeling. Once that is done, in your emmeans() call I think you will want to specify `offset = 0` (or log(1)), as that will move things from the count scale (based on the observed offsets) to the rate scale (based on a fixed offset of one unit).

Comment: @AmberEyedDog were you able to get help fitting a NB model? Also, looking at what you did, including `tran = "logit"` basically forces it to compute probabilities. What would happen if you just take that out?